# Decrease Button and LinearLayout with drawable as background

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout, text-size

I have a horizontal LinearLayout with 9 buttons in it. The LinearLayout has a background

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="9"
android:minHeight="0dp"//Also tried this
android:background="@drawable/llbackground">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minHeight="0dp"//tried this too
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

In code I give the user the opportunity to decrease the buttons textsize.
But the button itsself and the LinearLayout do not decrease with the textsize. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me paraphrase your question. So you want to let the user select a text size and the text size of the button will change but the size of the button doesn't. Am I right?

If that's your problem, you should not set the height to `"wrap_content"`. `"wrap_content"` basically means that the height will change with the content. i.e. When the size of the content (text) decreases, the height will decrease as much as the content does and vice versa.

Thus, you should set the height attribute to a constant. e.g. 60dp:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

See the change?

Also, xml comments are denoted with `<!--comment-->` instead of `//`

Comment: Yes I set it to "wrap-content" but that's not enought. From a speacial size on the button itsself does not decrease anymore.

Comment: @Lars3n95 There is a "special size" for button's height. I think `minHeight` is set on it by default, so it doesn't decrease unless you overwrite the property. Try setting it to a value of 1 if you absolutely want it to shrink, but keep in mind that it was set to make a `Button` follow the design guidelines, where each touchable surface should have at least a certain size in order to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Main thing your orientation is horizontal so it should be `width` that should be `wrap_content`
Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` , `android:minHeight="0dp"` (I think you want width here) , `android:layout_gravity="center"` you can give padding around text